# Is it possible to export a website into a native application?

Tags: 9

Say I have built a web application which does a certain well defined procedure such as medical self diagnosis with Drupal core only and I want to export it as a *nix executable (Android?) native application.

Is there any way to do it Drupal 9 (or should be, in Drupal 10)?

Comment: Drupal doesn't do this out of the box. Most of the boilerplate apps for Drupal connect to Drupal using the a REST APi https://www.drupal.org/docs/mobile-drupal-sites/native-mobile-application-development

Comment: You might have luck with wrapping your web app with Electron but never done it or seen it done hence just something you might want to explore on your own https://jojozhuang.github.io/tutorial/converting-web-app-to-desktop-app-with-electron/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot "export" Drupal into a native app.

A fairly common scenario is to use Drupal as the **backend** for native mobile apps-- in that case, you have a webserver running Drupal and then you make some apps (iOS, Android, etc.) and connect them to Drupal via REST, JSON:API, or GraphQL.

In this case, you have two or more codebases:

- Drupal
- Your apps that talk to Drupal (could be iOS, Android, or a frontend like React, Angular, etc.)

Can you use Drupal as the app itself though for Android or iOS?  No, not really.  You would have to run Drupal on some kind of webserver that would be bundled into the app, which is probably disallowed by Apple and Google and, in any case, is an unnecessarily complicated way of making a mobile app.

I have been building iOS and Android apps with Drupal using [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/) and had good results.  Ionic lets you use a frontend such as Angular, React, or Vue, and then you can create one codebase that lets you generate Android and iOS apps as well as a PWA.  This can talk to Drupal via JSON:API and works reasonably well, but it's a bunch of additional work on top of getting the Drupal site working-- you have to build the Ionic app using a non-Drupal technology stack.